# ajax form submission + modal

Tags: php, ajax

So the problem when I click on submit it gives me this + no data is inserted into the db :

[Screen shot of modal](http://prntscr.com/j4uagc)

I don't see any errors in the console.

my ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lmao").on("submit", function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#add_data_Modal .modal-header .modal-title').html("Result");
                $('#add_data_Modal .modal-body').html(data);
                $("#submitForm").remove();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#submitForm").on('click', function() {
        $("#lmao").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

my form + modal :

```
<div  id="add_data_Modal"class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Add mew course</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="block-content block-content-narrow">
                      <form id="lmao"class="js-validation-courses form-horizontal push-10-t" data-async data-target="#add_data_Modal" action="add_c.php" method="post">

                      <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-material">
                                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="course_title" name="course_title" >
                                      <label for="material-email">course title</label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                                      <div class="form-material">
                                          <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="course_cord"name="course_cord" >
                                          <label for="material-email">Course cord</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="form-material">
                                              <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="course_hours"name="course_hours" >
                                              <label for="material-email">hours </label>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                                              <div class="form-material">
                                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="course_price" name="course_price" >
                                                  <label for="material-email">price</label>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-sm-9">
                                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="add_course" id="submitForm" type="submit">Add course</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>

                      </div>
                  </div>


                </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
```

I have the add query in a separate file called add_c.PHP

so I have tried several answers from a lot of questions but I didn't manage to get something useful.

The PHP code in add_c.php :

[Php code - pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Y5zEnvjn)

My knowledge is very small about ajax so I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the value of `data`? If you put a breakpoint into the `success` function and inspect it, is it what you were expecting? If not, maybe what you were expecting is a property of `data`?

Comment: open your developer console and go to the network tab... fire your form ajax request and see if any request gets fired... the post request must be popping up, click on it, and click on response and see if you get any output

Comment: @sietse85 Yes I get in " Form Data " the output .. check the screenshot. [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/j4ula1)

Comment: i see 2 requests XHR getting fired with your code, for a start try changing the button type to: button and not submit, your code triggers submission twice it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, and the php file retrieves this post array

```
Array ( [course_title] => test [course_cord] => tet [course_hours] => tet [course_price] => tt )
```

your php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_course'])) {
```

add_course nevers gets posted, so it will never come into the if. Another issue is your form gets submitted twice the way you build it.

Change the button type into button, not submit. You already have a event listener on the button ;)

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="add_course" id="submitForm" type="button">Add course</button>
```

Comment: did you change your if statement? as i said in the post above?

Comment: I did you deserve it !. one more thing how I can reset the form and display success msg  on top of the form?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['course_title'])) {` for example ... also beware of possible SQL injection with the way you build it

Comment: but how? I use prepare  statement

Comment: I'm recommending that you follow some courses in javascript and php :) i cannot teach all, you have to teach yourself ;) There is tons of stuff on this subject on youtube for example for free ;)

Comment: i am not sure if prepared statements are 100 percent safe, just to be sure do some input validation on the post data ;)

Comment: also if you want to test for SQL injection attacks use nmap for example... that way you can see if your script is safe.